# Ellipses inscribed in convex quadrilaterals

Tags: conic-sections

This is a variant of [Ellipse to circumscribe a quadrilateral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184986/ellipse-to-circumscribe-a-quadrilateral)

Given any convex quadrilateral Q, is there at least one ellipse that is contained in Q and also touches all 4 sides of Q?

If the answer is "yes", then how does one find such an ellipse with maximum area?

Comment: The answer is yes.  There is an infinite number of ellipses that can be inscribed in a given convex quadrilateral $ABCD$.  And the minimum area of these ellipses is zero, as the ellipses turns into a line segment $AC$ or $BD$.  So you want to be looking at the ellipse with the maximum possible area instead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this slip. Edited the question.

Comment: Please see another post [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4382743/ellipse-inscribed-in-an-irregular-quadrilateral).

Comment: Thank you very much!